# How can I get an elements ID on mouseover and assign it to a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm beginning to learn how to use jQuery and am creating a small project management app. In the app you can drag employees from a list and drop them on to the different projects to assign them to it.

Inside each project div is a ul that I would like the employees to be appended to. The problem at the moment is I can get the employees added tot he div but they add outside the ul. I have tried setting up a variable to grab the element id from the project div and assign it to a variable. That variable would then be concatenated in the appendTo() call to add the item to the right list. This where I am having the problem. The variable keeps returning as [object Object].

Thanks for any help in advance. Here is a link to the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/imauld/2VU5j/9/) aswell.

HTML

```
<ul class='employee-list'>
    <li class='employee'>Ian</li>
    <li class='employee'>Danny</li>
</ul>
<div id='task-list'>
    <div id="task-1234" class='task'>
        <h3>Design new email</h3>
        <ul id="task-1234-employees" class='tasked-employees'></ul>
    </div>
    <div id ="task-4321" class='task'>
        <h3>Update Cart Code</h3>
        <ul id ="task-4321-employees" class='tasked-employees'></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jscript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(function () {
    var $taskID = $('.task').mouseover(function() {return this.id;});
    $(".employee").draggable({
        revert: 'invalid'
    }, {
        snap: '.task-slot',
        snapMode: 'inner'
    }, {
        appendTo: 'body',
        helper: 'clone'
    });
    $('.task').droppable({
        activeClass: "ui-state-default",
        hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
        accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).find(".placeholder").remove();
            $("<li class='task-slot'></li>").text(ui.draggable.text()).appendTo("#" + $taskID +"-employees");
        }
    });
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you have no need for the `mouse over` in the first place.

All the required info is available in the **ui** and **event** arguments of the `drop` method.

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        $(".employee").draggable({
            revert: 'invalid'
        }, {
            snap: '.task-slot',
            snapMode: 'inner'
        }, {
            appendTo: 'body',
            helper: 'clone'
        });
        $('.task').droppable({
            activeClass: "ui-state-default",
            hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
            accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
            drop: function (event, ui) {
                var employee = ui.draggable.text();
                $(this).find(".placeholder").remove();
                $("<li class='task-slot'></li>").text(employee)
                    .appendTo($(event.target).find('ul.tasked-employees'));
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/msuqk/)**